# Tensorflow Python Version Generate Different Results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training an autoencoder in Tensorflow. It looks like if we run the code using Python3, it works well as the loss decreases throughout the time. But when we run the same code in Python2, the loss just always hangs there. I am just confused,

Comment: Are you dividing integers with "/"? TensorFlow has the same behavior as Python in that regard, which differs between 2 and 3. Otherwise, could you try distilling the problem to code you could include in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expected to use the python version that you installed tensorflow with.  (See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html))

p.s. The lowest version they support seems to be Python2.7.

Comment: Yes. I have two python environment, one for python 2.7, and one for 3.4. I used conda to install all libraries.

Comment: Right, I am pointing out the fact that TensorFlow is installed in /usr/local/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/tensorflow probably implies there's a dependency.  Did you install tensorflow twice, once for each version?

Comment: Yes. I have two versions of tensor flow.